# Convert a long number to corresponding letter combinations

Tags: python, letters-and-numbers

Given a number, translate it to all possible combinations of corresponding letters. For example, if given the number `1234`, it should spit out `abcd`, `lcd`, and `awd` because the combinations of numbers corresponding to letters could be `1 2 3 4`, `12 3 4`, or `1 23 4`.

I was thinking of ways to do this in Python and I was honestly stumped. Any hints?

I basically only setup a simple system to convert single digit to letters so far.

Comment: Did you try doing anything by yourself? Could you post the code you've written so far?

Comment: a basic recursive approach should solve this easily...

Answer (score 1):

Make `str`.

Implement [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18407162/1028589).

Filter lists with a number over 26.

Write function that returns letters.

```
def alphabet(n):
    # return " abcde..."[n]
    return chr(n + 96)


def partition(lst):
    for i in range(1, len(lst)):
        for r in partition(lst[i:]):
            yield [lst[:i]] + r
    yield [lst]


def int2words(x):
    for lst in partition(str(x)):
        ints = [int(i) for i in lst]
        if all(i <= 26 for i in ints):
            yield "".join(alphabet(i) for i in ints)


x = 12121
print(list(int2words(x)))
# ['ababa', 'abau', 'abla', 'auba', 'auu', 'laba', 'lau', 'lla']
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not gonna give you a complete solution but an idea where to start:

I would transform the number to a string and iterate over the string, as the alphabet has 26 characters you would only have to check one- and two-digit numbers.

As in a comment above a recursive approach will do the trick, e.g.:

Number is 1234

*) Take first character -> number is 1

*) From there combine it with all remaining 1-digit numbers -->

```
      1 2 3 4
```

*) Then combine it with the next 2 digit number (if <= 26) and the remaining 1 digit numbers -->

```
      1 23 4
```

*) ...and so on

As i said, it's just an idea where to start, but basically its a recursive approach using combinatorics including checks if two digit numbers aren't greater then 26 and thus beyond the alphabet.

Comment: Don't know who downvoted you but he ought to be ashamed. Have an upvote.

Comment: for sure one of those people who search for complete implementations, but that's not how it's meant to be :-D